# How to stop being logged out of SSH sessions when locking the screen in OS X 10.9.1?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

Every time I lock my screen I get logged out of any active SSH sessions.

I've added the following to my ~/.ssh/config file, but I still get logged out:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

How can I stop being logged out of SSH sessions when I lock my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what is logging you out. Assuming that this is not an issue of changing Power settings (i.e. your machine is not sleeping), then most things that will break the connection can be solved by using a program called [`autossh`](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).

It's a wrapper around the regular `ssh` program (which it uses) and it implements a more robust keep-alive mechanism.

I got mine from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), but I'm sure [Fink](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/) has a port, too.

Comment: Doh. I think I was putting my mac to sleep because it's a macbook pro and there's no eject key. I'd read that was the button at the top right, but I think on newer macs it's just the power button.

Answer (score 9):

Two methods…

- Add the following to `/etc/ssh_config`:

  ```
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  ```
- Use `screen`:

  1. Create a new screen with `screen`, then use the terminal normally.
  2. When the connection breaks, reconnect normally.
  3. Run `screen -dr` to reattach.

Comment: I've used screen on the remote end to isolate myself from network interruptions. Does the TCPKeepAlive client setting prevent the remote server from disconnecting idle connections? My guess is a large fraction of ssh terminations are server side idle detections.

Comment: @bmike Not really sure — I've always used screen myself too (as I can resume from different computers), but a cursory Googling gave me [TCPKeepAlive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install an app called "Lock Me Now" from the app store and once it has been installed launch it and from the preferences "check" "Just Lock" under "Lock Type" which does the same thing as the screen saver timing out. Also for ease of use you can assign a keyboard shortcut to simplify the process of locking your Mac (I chose to use Command + L )

Comment: As of Sep 2016 there is no such app in the Mac app store.